# Cramer's rule for the intersection of a plane and a line in N-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, algebraic-geometry

A plane of rank 2 (not a hyperplane) can be represented parametrically as:
$$\mathbf{P}_P = \mathbf{S}_P + m\mathbf{o} + n\mathbf{p};\\
m, n \in \mathbb{R};\\
\mathbf{P}_P, \mathbf{S}_P, \mathbf{o}, \mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
where $\mathbf{S}_P$ is a point one the plane, $\mathbf{o}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ are linearly independent vectors.

A line is parametrically represented as:
$$\mathbf{P}_L = \mathbf{S}_L + t\mathbf{v};\\
t \in \mathbb{R};\\
\mathbf{P}_L, \mathbf{S}_L, \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
where $\mathbf{S}_L$ is a point on the line and $\mathbf{v}$ specifies the orientation of the line.

To calculate the intersection, we construct the equation $\mathbf{P}_P = \mathbf{P}_L$:
$$\mathbf{S}_L + t\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{S}_P + m\mathbf{o} + n\mathbf{p}\\
m\mathbf{o} + n\mathbf{p} - t\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{S}_L - \mathbf{S}_P\\
m\mathbf{o} + n\mathbf{p} + t(-\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{S}_L - \mathbf{S}_P$$
Now, if we were in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we could apply *Cramer's rule* in order to solve the equation for $m$, $n$ and $t$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{o}_x & \mathbf{p}_x & -\mathbf{v}_x \\
\mathbf{o}_y & \mathbf{p}_y & -\mathbf{v}_y \\
\mathbf{o}_z & \mathbf{p}_z & -\mathbf{v}_z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m \\
n \\
t \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{S}_{Lx} - \mathbf{S}_{Px} \\
\mathbf{S}_{Ly} - \mathbf{S}_{Py} \\
\mathbf{S}_{Lz} - \mathbf{S}_{Pz} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is fine in $\mathbb{R}^3$, because the matrix on the left hand side is square, but it doesn't work for higher dimensions.
**How can I elegantly solve for $t$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?** I don't need to know $m$ and $n$, but I don't mind having those aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot because the system is overdetermined if $n \geq 4$. It is thus easy to find cases where the equations are incompatible.

For example, the existence of a solution for

$$\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 0\\ 2}+t\pmatrix{1\\-1\\1\\-1}=x\pmatrix{1\\2\\1\\2}+y\pmatrix{1\\ 1 \\2\\2 } \ \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \begin{cases}1 + t  =  x+y \ \ (1) \\ 1 - t  =  2x+y  \ \ (2) \\ 0 +1t  =  x+2y
 \ \ (3) \\ 2 - t  =  2x+2y  \ \ (4)\end{cases}$$

by combining (1)+(4)-(2)-(3), would give $2=0$...

Comment: How can I geometrically interpret this? Does that mean that there is no such thing as an intersection of a plane and a line in 4D?

Comment: The "general" truth is : in $\mathbb{R^n}$  with $n \geq 4$, a line (1D space) and a 2D plane might or might not intersect (the probability that they do not intersect being...1).

Comment: ... Sorry for having somewhat disenchanted the $n$-dimensional world ;)